# Rails image asset helper not working in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.1 but any time i use image tag helper to call out an image it never brings out the image. So also wen i refresh my browser my style sheet is not rendered until i refresh the browser again. Does any one know how to come about this?
for instance

```
<%= image_tag('pic.png')%>
```

I am beginning to wonder if all this is a windows problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3.1 it looks like it is going to be /assets/image.png vs /images/image.png.  Place your images in app/assets/images. Worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are your images in app/assets/images? With Rails 3.1, this is the default location.

If you want to resort to having your images in public/images, you have to go into the application.rb, at the bottom, and set the asset pipeline to false.

I'm running Windows, so i'm not sure that's the issue.

The same goes for scaffolding. As for your stylesheet not being rendered until refresh, I'm not really sure. What browser are you using? I use Firefox 4.0.1.

Comment: i am also using firefox 4.0.1. I just checked my server log n it says

Comment: and it says undefined method >= for nil:NilClaass

Comment: as for my images, it does not display the image but rather displays the name of the image

Comment: Does it do this in another browser? Like Internet Explorer or Google Chrome?